# Perl Regex remove c comments with specific keywords

Tags: regex, perl

I have text like so:

1. /* blah blah blah blah */
2. /* blah blah blah jjj blah blah*/
3. /* blah blah*/
4. /* blah jjj
5. blah blah */
6. /* blah blah*/

I'd like to use perl regex to remove sections that start with /* ,contain jjj and end with */
(remove c comments that contain specific keywords...)
in the above example, I would want only lines 2, 4 and 5 to be removed

Your help is most appreciated,

Jack

Comment: Watch out for corner cases: `// single /* line comment` or: `char *str = "string /* literal";`

Comment: [File::Comments::Plugin::C](http://p3rl.org/File::Comments::Plugin::C) [String::Comments::Extract](http://p3rl.org/String::Comments::Extract) [Regexp::Common::comment](http://p3rl.org/Regexp::Common::comment)

Answer (score 4):

In general this is not very possible.  The C parse is very complicated with special handling due to comments, continuation lines, etc.

However, if you have a simple enough case, you might be able to do it.  I leave "// blah jjj" comment processing for you since you didn't mention it.

```
while ($ccode =~ s/(.*?)(\/\*.*?\*\/)//s)
{
   $out .= $1;
   my $comment = $2;
   $out .= $comment unless ($comment =~ /\bjjj\b/);
}
$out .= $ccode;
```

Comment: Some examples of more complex cases that are much harder to handle: string literals that contain "/*" or "*/"; depending on how you parse it, multi-line comments; comments that have code _after_ them: `int /* this is an integer jjj */ j = 2;` (the regex can be modified to handle it); the keyword coming right at the beginning or end of a comment without spaces: `/*jjj blah */` `/* blah jjj*/` (the regex/logic can be modified to handle it, but it's starting to get complicated), and so on. You need a proper C lexer to handle this correctly for all cases in valid C code.

Comment: I agree with your statement that you need a proper C parser to do the work properly, after all I said that.  Not handling string literals that contain comments is a great example.  However, it does handle comments embedded in code and comments without spaces (though the jjj detection may not--I will update that).

Comment: Right. I wasn't picking apart your solution, but rather illustrating your point that in general, it's not possible to do simply. Any simple solution will have several points of failure. There are some things that can be fixed by changing the logic/regex, but the more you fix, the more complex it becomes, until you're swimming in a sea of unreadable regex that's next to impossible to debug.