# Only find multiline C comment but not single line C comments

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose I have this text:

```
cat file
/* comment */ not a comment /* another comment */

/* delete this  *
/* multiline    *
/* comment      */

/*************
/* and this  *  
/************/
The End
```

I can use the `perl` with a conditional `? :`  to delete only the multiline comment:

```
perl -0777 -pE 's/(\/\*(?:\*(?!\/)|[^*])*\*\/)/($1=~qr"\R") ? "" : $1/eg;' file
```

Prints:

```
/* comment */ not a comment /* another comment */




The End
```

Without the conditional:

```
perl -0777 -pE 's/(\/\*(?:\*(?!\/)|[^*])*\*\/)//g;' file
 not a comment 




The End
```

Is there a way to delete only multiline C style comments with a regex only? ie, not use the perl conditional code in the replacement?

Comment: Thanks for that link. Unless I am missing something, it does not answer how to limit the match to only multiline comments. The closest thing I found was [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417436/perl-regex-remove-c-comments-with-specific-keywords) which is essentially the same as my conditional approach.

Comment: _"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think_ “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  _Now they have two problems."_  -- [Jamie Zawinski](http://www.jwz.org/)

Comment: *"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think* “I know, I'll ask a question on Stack Overflow about a regular expression” *Now they have received a very nice solution."*

Comment: @sin: very very fair points. I guess I was not trying to write a full comment compiler. C comment are potentially [perverse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2394918/298607). I am just shooting for the 90% cases.

Comment: Ok sorry, it looks like it is a script file target. I misread it as C language file. But it doesn't have to be that perverse for C C++ . A simple callback replacement logic is all that's needed since this template maches it all (/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n)|("(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|[\S\s][^/"'\\]*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a SKIP/FAIL approach:

```
perl -0777 -pe's~/\*\N*?\*/(*SKIP)^|/\*.*?\*/~~gs' file
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/IwPlfr/1)

`\N` matches all that isn't a line-break
The dot matches all characters including newlines since the s flag is used.

The first branch matches "inline" comments, and is forced to fail with `^` (shorter than writing `(*F)` or `(*FAIL)` but same result). The `(*SKIP)` backtracking control verb forces to not retry previous positions, so the next attempts starts after the position of the closing `*/`.

The second branch matches remaining comments that are necessarly multiline.

---

A shorter variant, with the same two branches but this time using `\K` to excludes the consumed characters from the match result:

```
perl -0777 -pe's~/\*\N*?\*/\K|/\*.*?\*/~~gs' file
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/IwPlfr/2)

This time the first branch succeeds, but since all characters before `\K` are removed from the match result, the remaining empty string is replaced with an empty string.

---

These two search/replace aren't very different than doing the more portable:

```
s~(/\*.*?\*/)|/\*[\s\S]*?\*/~$1~g
```

but with less efforts (no capture group needed, empty replacement string).

Comment: These are both very efficient. I like the portable version too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```perl
perl -0777 -pe 's~/\*(?:(?!\*/|/\*).)*\R(?s).*?\*/~~g' file
```

The pattern matches

- `/\*` - a `/*` string
- `(?:(?!\*/|/\*).)*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars, each of which is not a starting char of a `*/` and `/*` char sequences
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `(?s)` - now, `.` will also match line breaks
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\*/` - a `*/` substring.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xD3M3z/1).